# Detect local data update in Firebase

Tags: firebase

When I call setValue while my user is offline in my Android app, Firebase provides a snapshot of the change to my listener from the local store,even though the change hasn't been committed to the server. I understand that Firebase will make an effort to sync with the server when connectivity is restored, but if the app restarts that change is lost forever.

I've already got a custom local store for all my data, and I was hoping I could keep track of uncommitted changes myself, clearing a dirty bit when I hear back from the server of a successful setValue. But that doesn't seem possible if the local store is pretending the date is committed.

I don't think I want to use disk persistence (since I already have my own). Is there a way to tell when the update is from the local store vs a real server commit? Or maybe I should use a completion listener to clear the dirty bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that Firebase will make an effort to sync with the server when connectivity is restored, but if the app restarts that change is lost forever.

The default behavior is indeed that the pending writes are kept in memory. You can however easily change that by [enabling disk persistence](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-enabling-offline-support).

```
Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

But since you indicate you don't want to use that, the alternative is to use a CompletionListener to detect when the changes have been committed to the database on Firebase's servers:

```
ref.setValue("I'm writing data", new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
        if (firebaseError != null) {
            System.out.println("Data could not be saved. " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
        }
    }
});
```

Note that completion listeners are not persisted to disk. So even if you enable dis persistence, the completion callbacks will *not* fire when pending writes are fulfilled after an app restart. So don't try to mix disk persistence or completion listeners.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I tested the completion listener earlier this morning and it seems to do the job.

Comment: what if I have no internet and I want to send messages when device is Online?